# Calculating getDmlStatements

Tags: apex, governorlimits, limits

I am wondering how I can calculate DMLStatements.
The test below adds unexpectly 3 instead of 1 -> after insert. Why?

```
System.debug( Limits.getDmlStatements( ) );//0
Account ac = new Account( Name = 'LOLA' );
System.debug( Limits.getDmlStatements( ) );//0
insert ac;
System.debug( Limits.getDmlStatements( ) );//3 ???
List<Account> accounts = [ SELECT Id FROM Account where Name = 'LOLA' LIMIT 1 ];
delete accounts;
System.debug( Limits.getDmlStatements( ) );//7 ???
Database.emptyRecycleBin( accounts );
System.debug( Limits.getDmlStatements( ) );//8
```

Comment: Any chance that you have a trigger/process builder/flow which does more DML changes?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. So the general rule is adding one per one DML operation?

Comment: every DML operation is DML statement indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing 3 DML statements used because you're using 2 additional DML statements as part of the code that is run when you insert your `Account`. Likewise, when you delete your `Account`, additional things are being run, and that seems to account for 3 additional DML statements.

The important point here is that *the code you've provided us isn't the only code that is being run*. DML causes triggers to run (if they exist and are set up to handle whatever DML operation you're running), those triggers can cause other triggers to run, or run code in apex classes, or cause workflow to perform a field update, etc...

Salesforce calls this (the code you run + everything else that's run because of it) a *transaction*, and governor limits (like DML statements) are a limit applied to the transaction as a whole. Any work that is done between the start and end of your transaction is counted.